# OpenJDK Static Build

Tags: java, jvm

I am new to OpenJDK,
so I'd like to apologize if it's a known issue or there is already a way to get over it.

Currently, I am trying to 'static build' the OpenJDK
so that I can remove all dynamic library dependencies
when I use the tools like java, javac, etc.

For that purpose, I found an option called '--enable-static-build' fed to the configure file.
However, it seems like it's not supported (even not allowed to enable) at the current mainstream.

Would there be any workaround to enable that option for static build?
Or, does anyone know any specific branch or GitHub tag where the static build works fine by any chance?

Many thanks in advance!

I have tried to use the configure option, --enable-static-build, but didn't work.

Comment: Why do you need that kind of static build?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to do some simulation on FPGAs. Due to the limited memory size, the FPGA file system can't contain much (like dependencies or libraries). So, I am thinking of simply putting statically compiled binaries and running them.

Comment: Did you think about [GraalVM's `native-image`](https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/reference-manual/native-image/) tool before compiling OpenJDK by yourself? It does [support static binaries with `musl` and mostly-static binaries](https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/reference-manual/native-image/StaticImages/). `native-image` does have a few limitations though.